# SVD: What do the resulting matrices mean with respect to document summarisation and similarity

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, svd, summarization

I'm currently trying to use SVD to summarise documents, and then find similarities between documents. My question is, what do the resulting matrices actually mean, and how can I use them, for example to get the summarisation of one document, or to get a summarisation of all documents?

I have already built a term-document matrix, in the form of a 2D list, with one list per term, where each list contains the number of times a term appears in each document.

My knowledge of linear algebra is limited, so please don't give a maths heavy explanation. Furthermore, I have already googled a lot, and looked at many online pages to try to understand, but at this point, I feel I just need a simple explanation of how to achieve what I want.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I'm still trying to wrap my head around this as well. I have a tf-idf score for each document/term pair so I could run an SVD on that matrix, but i'm not sure what to do with the resulting info.